# LASSO-type regressions with non-negative continuous dependent variable (dependent var)

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am using "glmnet" package (in R) mostly to perform regularized linear regression.

However I am wondering if it can perform LASSO-type regressions with **non-negative (integer) continuous (dependent) outcome variable**.

I can use family = poisson, but the outcome variable is **not** specifically "count" variable. It is just a continuous variable with lower limit 0.

I aware of "lower.limits" function, but I guess it is for covariates (independent variables). (Please correct me if my understanding of this function not right.)

I look forward to hearing from you all! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are right that setting lower limit in glmnet is meant for covariates. Poisson will set a lower limit to zero because you exponentiate to get back the "counts".

Going along those lines, most likely it will work if you transform your response variable. One quick way is to take the log of your response variable, do the fit and transform it back, this will ensure that it's always positive.  you have to deal with zeros

An alternative is a power transformation. There's a lot to think about and I can only try a [two parameter box-cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) with a dataset since you did not provide yours:

```
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
library(geoR)
data(BostonHousing)
data = BostonHousing
data$chas=as.numeric(data$chas)

# change it to min 0 and max 1
data$medv = (data$medv-min(data$medv))/diff(range(data$medv))
```

Then here I use a quick approximation via pca (without fitting all the variables) to get the suitable lambda1 and lambda2 :

```
bcfit = boxcoxfit(object = data[,14], 
xmat = prcomp(data[,-14],scale=TRUE,center=TRUE)$x[,1:2],
lambda2=TRUE)

bcfit
Fitted parameters:
     lambda     lambda2       beta0       beta1       beta2     sigmasq 
 0.42696313  0.00001000 -0.83074178 -0.09876102  0.08970137  0.05655903 

Convergence code returned by optim: 0
```

Check the lambda2, it is the one thats critical for deciding whether you get a negative value.. It should be rather small.

Create the functions to power transform:

```
bct = function(y,l1,l2){((y+l2)^l1 -1)/l1}
bctinverse = function(y,l1,l2){(y*l1+1)^(1/l1) -l2}
```

Now we transform the response:

```
data$medv_trans = bct(data$medv,bcfit$lambda[1],bcfit$lambda[2])
```

And fit glmnet:

```
fit = glmnet(x=as.matrix(data[,1:13]),y=data$medv_trans,nlambda=500)
```

Get predictions over all lambdas, and you can see there's no negative predictions once you transform back:

```
pred = predict(fit,as.matrix(data[,1:13]))
range(bctinverse(pred,bcfit$lambda[1],bcfit$lambda[2]))
[1] 0.006690685 0.918473356
```

And let's say we do a fit with cv:

```
fit = cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(data[,1:13]),y=data$medv_trans)
pred = predict(fit,as.matrix(data[,1:13]))
pred_transformed = bctinverse(pred,bcfit$lambda[1],bcfit$lambda[2]
plot(data$medv,pred_transformed,xlab="orig response",ylab="predictions")
```

[image]

Comment: I sincerely appreciate it, @StupidWolf. Indeed, I think you should change your username to SmartWolf! :-)

Comment: I just got a couple of questions. 
(1) Why did you use pca for the Box-Cox transformation? If the cumulative proportion (of variance) of two PCs is about only 50%, is it still worth to use pca?
(2) I guess the first question leads me to having low prediction coefficient. In your case, prediction coefficients spreads from 0 to 0.8. However, in my case the prediction coefficients is almost between 0 and 0.1. Do you perhaps any idea on this issue?

Comment: To do a boxcox, you need to find a suitable lambda1 and lambda2. You can also regress it against all the variables, but if your data is large this might be laborious and I reduced it down with PCA. 50% is ok if you have a large dataset. I mean it should be enough to find a good lambda parameter

Comment: you mean the predicted values i guess.. what is your dataset like? How many variables are used in the end? You can do some checks with ```fit = cv.glmnet(...) ; plot(fit)``` see how the deviance lows like..

Comment: Thank you so much for revisiting this question post, @StupidWlof ! 
The dataset is not too large (50 X 24 dimensional matrix). I have 50 subjects (people) and 23 covariates (19 of them is continuous from negative inf. to positive inf., and the remaining 4 of them are positive integer-valued.). And, of course, there is 1 outcome variable (range from 0 to 55). When I plot the cv.glmnet, then the mse is super high like 6 or 7 (as expected though...). It is shame that I cannot upload a picture via the comment.

Comment: And one "critical" difference between your example (Boston) and mine is that the shape of histogram of the outcome variable. 
In your case, hist(data$medv) has normal-like shape. However, in my case, the histogram of the outcome variable is highly skewed to the right, thus making us to feel that this is something like Poisson. The same phenomenon happens after Box-Cox transformation.

Comment: Hi @rudgus51998, did you actually normalize the values like i did to get a range from 0 to 1? You don't need to. I did that only because data$medv is not near zero. I needed that to show it doesn't go negative. Try the boxcox on your actual data, it should be ok